# R: Referring to a column created earlier in the same custom function with data masking functions/tidyverse

Tags: r, functional-programming, tidyverse

R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
R Studio Version 1.2.5042

library(tidyverse package)

I'm creating a function. I hoped someone could show me how to refer to a column that I have added via mutate to a dataframe earlier on in the same function where i've used the enquo(), !!() approach.

```
               x <- function(df1, df2, df1_col1, offset) 

                    df1_col1 <- enquo(df1_col1)
                    varname1 <- paste0("Text", as_label(df1_col1))
                  
                    df1 <- df1 %>% 
                      mutate( (!!varname1) := lag( (!!dataframe_col1) ) 

                    df3_new <- df2 %>%
                      full_join(df1, by = "whatever_variable") %>%
                      filter( (!!varname1) > d2f_col)                # How do you correctly reference the vales in the newly created varname column?
```

In words in case the code above is confusing, I add a column to df1. I then want to filter df2 for any rows that are lower than the values created in the column I added to df1.

I haven't added code or data, but I could add if it would help. Thankyou in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

x <- function(df1, df2, df1_col1, offset) {

  varname1 <- paste0("Text", deparse(substitute(df1_col1)))

  df1 <- df1 %>% mutate({{varname1}} := lag({{dataframe_col1}})) 

  df3_new <- df2 %>% 
                full_join(df1, by = "whatever_variable") %>% 
                filter(!!sym(varname1) > df2_col)  
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I made an error in the most important bit of my dummy code above. I've now ammended it. The last line read

Comment: filter( df1_col1 > df2_col) and it should have read filter(varname1 > df2_col). I've tried the using the newly created column via df1[varname!], but R says the column doesn't exist. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: @Kunal Can you check the updated answer? Why do you pass offset as variable in the function when you don't use it.

Comment: Thankyou for this! I should have removed the offset variable here, I use it in the df1 pipe t add on the the result of the lag in the varname1 column

Comment: It worked a treat, Thankyou! Just clicked the check mark